# Why does knitr::spin not render numbering when rmarkdown::render does?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have a `analysis_20170615_test_of_spin_vs_ctrl_shift_k.R` file containing the following:

```
#' This is a test of spin reading numbering in markdown.
#'  
#' #. Hi this should be number 1.
#'     + this should be a bullet.
#' #. This should be number 2.
#'     + this should be a second bullet.
#'
```

I convert this file into a html document two ways, one by using the `rmarkdown::render` from RStudio's `CTRL-SHIFT-K` shortcut. The [helpfile linked](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_report_from_r_script.html) says:

> Note that when using rmarkdown::render the spin function is called automatically under the hood as part of rendering

My problem is that the numbers and bullets are not rendered when I call `knitr::spin('analysis_20170615_test_of_spin_vs_ctrl_shift_k.R')` directly.

E.g.[image]

Comment: (numbers can be rendered with `spin` as long as you use `1.` and `2.` instead of `#.`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`knitr::spin()` uses the [**markdown**](https://cran.rstudio.com/package=markdown) package to render Markdown to HTML, which does not support `#.` as the syntax for numbered lists. `rmarkdown::render()` uses Pandoc, which supports `#.`. Unless you know what you are doing, it is strongly recommended that you use the **rmarkdown** package instead of **markdown**.

To clarify, `rmarkdown::render()` calls `knitr::spin()` to convert `.R` to `.Rmd`, and then it is compiled through `knitr::knit()` and `rmarkdown::pandoc_convert()`. `rmarkdown::render()` does not directly produce the HTML output from `knitr::spin()`.